# Do IP-per-win boosts stack with timed boosts?

Tags: league-of-legends

I want to buy a per-win boost and a timed boost. Will they stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, per win IP boosts and timed boosts stack together.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Influence_Points#Trivia